# iPad Player has a striked out play button for mp4 files sometimes - html5 video tag

Tags: ipad, html5-video, mp4

I have a HTML5 video tag that serves some mp4 files generated by us and stored on a server which mostly works alright.

But sometimes, the play button is striked out on ipad and the video is not playable. The same video is playable at a different instant.

I cant seem to figure the reason why this happens, that too only sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using iOS 3.0? If so there used to be a lot of issues. Including a poster could break the video, and even just including an external javascript could mess it up.